# Why is my array not populating with successfully obtained information from my for-loop?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, for-loop, int

I have a dateArray that collects an array of Integer arrays, for example: [[24,4,2016], [29,4,2016], [23, 4, 2016]]. I am essentially trying to pull hard coded data into this array. I am successfully obtaining it in the first print function but then the array is not populating. So my console outputs the following: 
[24, 4, 2016]
nil
[29, 4, 2016]
nil
[20, 4, 2016]
nil
[14, 4, 2016]
nil. So there is an issue in filling the array - any clues?

```
var dateArray: [[Int]]? 

 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    dateArray?.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

    for object in newentry.diaryArray {

        print(object["date"] as! [Int])
        dateArray?.append(object["date"] as! [Int])
         print(dateArray)
    }


}
```

Comment: I am not sure about Swift, but I think you should initialize your dateArray. Can you tell me if that works?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the dateArray, then you can add your data to your Array.